# Why this question should be closed

Tags: discussion, magento2

Actually there is (4close) requests for the bellow question, and I think it will be closed, it's a pity that the others as soon as they see a close vote, they continue closing :

[How to customise the shipping form?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242074/how-to-customise-the-shipping-form)

We see well the comment of @Amit Bera (Moderator) :

> Oriol, please don't post a single line command. Please put what you
>   have tried so far?

The user (Oriol) has said he doesn't know and he could not find the template, can we close this topic for a illegitimate question ? and @Amit Bera how do you want him to post something since he didn't even find the path of that form ?

> **Note:** I don't know this person and I don't defend him, it's for the good sense and the good of everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Price Question is open Now.

As a moderator, I don't think the close votes over this question are not wrong since the user did not post some other details.

On the first post of the question, the user only asked he has customized,  as per as MSE  rules it went to `too broad` and `unclear what you're asking` rules. This question is not clear what he/She want. If you have tried to answer it then there are a lot of scenarios coming over the question, like  **which and what section of shipping form will customize!**.

> @Amit Bera how do you want him to post something since he didn't even
>   find the path of that form?

Price, the user never mentioned that he/she `didn't find the path and etc..`

and **Sorry, I don't understand how you have understood that he/she did not find the path etc as I don't see this type of work in comment and question**.

After my comment, the user has cleared the exact purpose of his/her question.

Now, you say me which question looks better?
**Customization at shipping form**

or

**Add a field like a number phone or delete the company field at shipping form** .

Price, if we will allow this type of questions at MSE then it will start breaking Purpose of StackExchange.

During my time at MSE, I see lots of posts which just copied here client requests also see lots which were not clear. I don't think those are right.

For the last comment, I have reopened this question.

At last, thank you for your question.  I respect your concern.

Comment: Amit, thank you for your answer, you asked me how I did to understand that the user didn't find the path, so well look at the first original question without the edit,  the question was : "I want custom the shipping form, but i cant find it. Where would the path of the file be?" you see, for me it was clear that he/she is looking for the path So, I just say that it's not against you or whatever, as I said it's for the good sense and the good of SE, and as you are a professional I know you have well understood what I meant.