# (Close) votes not really checked before?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

It happens really often that questions are closed because broadness/unclarity, but its not correct in many cases ... example ...

> Q: [Why this question should be closed](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/why-this-question-should-be-closed)

Another example from last days is: [Magento 2 Bottle Deposit Extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241540/magento-2-bottle-deposit-extension)

This was very clear for me from the first post (a know bottle deposit here in germany ;)), but "Sukumar Gorai" flagged it as unclear b/c he had no clue what was meant.

The question was edited (after first or second "close" flag), so that everybody could understand what he was asking for, but it seems to be closed w/o further reading.

I had complete code to share, but I'm not able to ...

**Suggestions:**

- really check if edits were made since 1st vote
- if you disagree to close votes ... leave a comment for other reviewers

Btw ... to close 5 votes are required, what happens if 4 vote to leave open? Is it closed on 5th vote or does it require 4 other votes to close?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sv3n, the question is open now.

I don't think the close over of `Magento 2 Bottle Deposit Extension` is not wrong until the question updated by `bambamboole` .

From the begining of the post, the question is not clear for any user who has not worked on this type of extension, so it is too tough to answer on that question at that time.I hope you have agree with me on this point.

> The question was edited (after first or second "close" flag), so that everybody could understand what he was asking for, but it seems to be closed w/o further reading

I agree with you. The first vote is valid but other votes doesn't seem  right as the user already given a good description on the question.

As a community member, we can suggest to our colleagues to give more time to read the questions before closing those questions.

Also, as Magento stackexchange's moderator, I am a requesting to all members, if you guys have any issue like this question, please reopen it or post here, we will open those question.

Comment: Sure @amitbera . Any question like this i will post here.

Comment: Thanks for reopen. I guess most european user know about "bottle deposit" w/o further explaination (at least in germany and some others).  Its realted to some laws that you have to add a deposit for (most) glass bottles you buy. E.g. if you buy a bottle of beer, you have to add 0,08 € deposit. But yes, for others it was not really clear, unit the edit :)

Comment: It was an honest mistake @sv3n , I think things which are known/apply for a small region should be mentioned explicitly.